# Machine Learning with Encryption

Tags: encryption

Machine Learning is sometimes associated with cryptography. Many of such cross field studies have been majorly done in use of machine learning for cryptanalysis/decryption. I am interested in knowing that can machine learning be used in anyway for encryption. Googling it did not give any relevant results. Are there any references or resources on this domain? Or is this idea impractical without much future scope?

Comment: The crypto techniques somewhat related to machine learning that I know of are 1) using SAT solvers as part of cryptoanalysis 2) Learning with error problems in lattice based crypto

Comment: You might be able to throw machine learning at side-channel or meta data. But that's a bit beyond crypto per-se.

Comment: Related questions: [Any practical uses of machine learning for cryptography?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/any-practical-uses-of-machine-learning-for-cryptography) and [Cryptography based upon neural networks](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/cryptography-based-upon-neural-networks)