# Are there any homomorphic first and second preimage resistant (cryptographic) hash functions?

Tags: hash, homomorphic-encryption, preimage-resistance

Are there any homomorphic cryptographic hash functions that satisfy $\text{H(A + B)} = \text{H(A)} + \text{H(B)}$ which maintaining pre-image resistance

Comment: You can easily find a set of inputs whose images are a basis (over the field with two elements) of the range. Write the target hash value as sum of elements of the basis and use that $H$ is homomorphic.

Comment: Realted [Are there any practical implementation of a homomorphic hashing or signature scheme?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6497/18298) and [Are there cryptographic hash functions with homomorphic properties?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19063/18298)

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you mean with "+"? I thought of bitwise addition (xor), but it could be as well addition in any abelian group or even string concatenation.

Comment: Hey sorry, in any abelian group operation. I don't think any basis over the field with two elements would work :\

Answer (score 2):

Fix a finite group $G$ of order $\ell$, written additively, in which discrete logarithms are difficult.  Fix a standard base point $P \in G$ of large prime order.  The function $H\colon \mathbb Z/\ell \mathbb Z \to G$ given by $$H(n) := [n]P = \underbrace{P + \cdots + P}_{\text{$n$ times}}$$ is a preimage-resistant homomorphism: $H(n + m) = H(n) + H(m)$, and finding preimages is exactly finding discrete logarithms.

Of course, if $\ell$ is prime, then $H$ is injective and so doesn't compress its input at all; while if $\ell$ is composite, then $H$ is not collision-resistant since $H(n + \operatorname{ord} P) = H(n)$ for all $n$.  See the linked answers to address collision resistance.